# Change MVC Home Landing Page: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' has been registered

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I tried changing the landing page of my web page mvc application using this command.

I received this error below. How would I resolve it?

```
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection services, IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {


        app.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Products/Index", "");
        });
```

**Error:**

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' has been registered.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `ConfigureServices` method in order to configure services and DI:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Products/Index", "");
    });
}
```

The `Configure` method should be used to configure the HTTP pipeline (i.e. `app.UseMvc();`)

For further read, see [App startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2)